# SFDX package list

Tags: salesforcedx, package

My sfdx-project looks like this :

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "dreamhouse",
            "versionNumber": "3.0.0.NEXT",
            "versionName": "Winter '19"
        },
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "package": "myDreamhouse",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "default": false
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "44.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "dreamhouse": "0Ho1I000000XZDVSA4",
        "dreamhouse@2.0.0-4": "04t1I0000036seVQAQ",
        "dreamhouse@3.0.0-5": "04t1I0000036u98QAA",
        "myDreamhouse": "0Ho1i000000CaSKCA0"
    }
}
```

When I run `sfdx force:package:list` I get :

```
NAMESPACE PREFIX  NAME          ID                  ALIAS         DESCRIPTION         TYPE
────────────────  ────────────  ──────────────────  ────────────  ──────────────────  ────────
                  dreamhouse    0Ho1i000000CaSFCA0                Dreamhouse package  Unlocked
                  myDreamhouse  0Ho1i000000CaSKCA0  myDreamhouse  My Package          Unlocked
```

Where the ID of dreamhouse package (in list) doesn't match the one in json file. I did run `sfdx force:package:create --name dreamhouse --description "My Package" --packagetype Unlocked --path force-app --nonamespace --targetdevhubusername DevHub` from the trailhead but with an error (I didn't remove the package info prior)

If I remove myDreamhouse from packageDirectories and packageAliases and I run list command again I get the same result (without any alias for myDreamhouse package).

So my question is : What's happening when you run package:create ? (it seems to do more that just update the description json file) And where the command package:list fetch all the informations needed ?

Answer (score 0):

***force:package:create*** creates the Package ID for the package name and the path .The fact that you have specified same path for both the packages is weird .

***force:package:list*** This lists down all the packages created for the Devhub you are authenticated to via the SFDX CLI .This is stored in the server .

Since you ran into errors that clearly means the package was not created .